# How to run single Android local unit test using gradle 2.4. Test filtering is not supported

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, gradle

I'm using gradle to build my android project and am not able to run single local unit test. I have several test classes and one of them is `MockServerTest` and I only want to run test methods in this class.
I tried using `gradle -Dtest.single=MockServerTest test` but it turned out running all my tests, including these in other test classes.
I also tried `gradle test --tests MockServerTest` but an error occurred said

```
Test filtering is not supported for given version of junit. Please upgrade junit version to at least 4.6.
```

But I'm using junit 4.12 in my gradle file

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

I'm using gradle 2.4 with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3`.
Also, how can I run a single test method inside a single test class?

BTW, I'm able to run single test method inside Android Studio, by right clicking on the test method and select `run targetTestMethod()` from the menu. But how can I achieve this in the terminal? I guess Android Studio also trigger a certain command to do this. How can I see what that command is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out myself. I have to run

`gradle testDebug --tests com.my.package.TestClassName`

There are two things to note here.
1. You have to use `gradle testDebug` or `gradle testRelease` instead of just `gradle test`. If you have build variant, you have to use `gradle testVariantNameDebug` or `gradle testVariantNameRelease`
2. You have to specify the whole qualified class name, means including the package name.

Comment: When I try this approach, I get the following error:                                             * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sdk:testDebugUnitTest'.
> Test filtering is not supported for given version of JUnit. Please upgrade JUnit version to at least 4.6.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Android Gradle plugin DSL](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current) to set up test tasks filters like this:

```
android {
  testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
      it.testNameIncludePattern = "*.SomeTest"
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more information on `testOptions` [here](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.TestOptions.UnitTestOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.TestOptions.UnitTestOptions:all%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) and filters [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestFilter.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `gradle test -Dtest.single=MockServerTest`? More information can be found [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_test).

Comment: Yes, but instead of running a single test class, it runs all my test classes and all the test methods.